# Simplest Way to Delete Object with Entity Framework 4

Tags: .net, winforms, entity-framework-4

Ack! I'm new to Entity Framework and am trying to find the simplest way to delete an item.

I have a listbox with the datasource set to TagCategory objects from the database. This is working fine. Now I'd like to delete the selected item. So I do something like this:

```
TagCategory category = (TagCategory)lstCategories.SelectedItem;
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    context.AttachTo("TagCategories", category);
    context.DeleteObject(category);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This seems straight forward enough, but it doesn't work. Nothing is deleted, no error message, nothing.

So I see I can instead do something like this:

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    string cmd = String.Format("DELETE FROM TagCategory WHERE TagCatID=@ID",
        category.TagCatID));
    context.ExecuteStoreCommand(qry);
}
```

That seems to work. So do I just go with what works, or is Entity Framework 4 actually capable of doing this?

***EDIT: Nevermind. In fact, I had another issue that prevented the code form executing. Both snippets I posted seem to work okay. My apologies.***

Comment: by the way, try not to use `AttachTo` on the context. Use `ObjectSet<T>.Attach`. e.g `context.TagCategories.Attach(category)`. And likewise `context.Categories.Delete(category)` instead of `context.DeleteObject(category)`.

Comment: @RPM1984: I had wondered about that and if both syntaxes did the same thing. Can you say why Attach() on the entity is better?

Comment: isn't it obvious? one is strongly typed, one is a magic string. if you refactor your model you will get runtime errors. with `Attach` you'll get a compilation error. anytime you put a magic string *anywhere* in an application, ask yourself why, and see if it can be avoided.

Comment: @RPM1984: Okay, so they both work the same, but one is strongly typed. I understood that but I always ask whenever someone says to try not to do something. Thanks.

Comment: Now it's "Remove" and not "Delete," btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use stub entity, something like this:

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
     var tagCategory = new TagCategory
     {
         PostId = category.TagCatID
     };
     context.TagCategories.Attach(tagCategory);
     context.DeleteObject(tagCategory);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Why is this helpful? In my code, category is already a TagCategory and already has the ID set. Am I missing anything?

Comment: try attaching it and see if it works, otherwise just create a stumb entity assign the ID only and attach to the context, then you can perform the delete, here is a good description of it: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Working_with_Ids_in_the_Entity_Framework.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's any different from what I was trying before. I tried your code (changing PostId to TagCatID) but got the same result.

Comment: if you are using SQL on the back end, try running the SQL Server Profiler and capture the trace of what is executing against your DB, at least you will find out if it makes it that far and whats the raw SQL

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can use `AttachTo()` for this. Depends on how you filled the ListBox.

What ought to work:

```
  var Key = context.CreateEntityKey("TagCategory", category);
  Object original;
  if (context.TryGetObjectByKey(Key, out original))
  {
        context.DeleteObject(original);
        context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Comment: I've used AttachTo() to successfully change the object's values and then save them. I tried the code above. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
// using the Find method of DBContext to retrieve the record you wish to delete
// works for me
// below code taken from a working WPF application using sdf database 

if (this.TransactionsDataGrid.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    Transaction transaction = this.TransactionsDataGrid.SelectedItem as Transaction;
    if (transaction != null)
    {
        using (BilliEntities context = new BilliEntities())
        {
           try
           {
               Transaction trans = context.Transactions.Find(transaction.TransactionId);
               if (trans != null)
               {
                   // observable collection for datagrid
                   this.Transactions.Remove(transaction);
                   context.Transactions.Remove(trans);
                   context.SaveChanges();
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              // for debugging
           }
        }
     }
 }
```