# Why can I not delete an entity with just .DeleteObject(o)?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

This code works :

```
var c = cboCustomer.SelectedItem as Customer;
var t = cboTrailer.SelectedItem as Trailer;
using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
{
   db.Attach(c);
   db.Attach(t); 
   c.Trailers.Remove(t);
   db.DeleteObject(t);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I dont understand why I cannot just do :

```
db.Attach(t);
db.DeleteObject(t);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If I try that I get :

**Entities in 'CAPSContainer.Trailers' participate in the 'CustomerTrailer' relationship. 0 related 'Customer' were found. 1 'Customer' is expected.**

I am using EF 5.0 Model first and here is part of the edmx diagram :

[image]

I am finding it hard to understand why, please help.

**UPDATE 1 (As suggested by Boomer):**

```
            using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
            {
                db.Attach(c);
                //db.Attach(t);
                //c.Trailers.Remove(t);
                db.DeleteObject(t);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Returns :

**The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.**

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787652/simplest-way-to-delete-object-with-entity-framework-4) shows a simple delete in entity framework

Comment: @Boomer unfortunately that's what I am saying, the simple delete is giving the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is obvious since the Customer is required in this relation. It is like you are inserting a Trailer record in the database without specifying the CustomerID, can you do that in SQL?

A better approach will be to delete that object by ID for example. In that case, you don't have to attach `t` before deleting it:

```
using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
{   
    db.DeleteObject(db.Trailers.Where(p => p.ID == t.ID));
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or when loading all the `Trailers` (within the dropdown), you should also get the `Customer` with it and any other mandatory entity attached.

Comment: I get the same error if I just omit c.Trailers.Remove(t); ... surely I shouldnt have to delete the trailer, and the relationship in two steps.

Comment: the problem is in db.attach(t) I presume

Comment: I didn't mean that you remove db.attach(t), I am telling you that the error comes from that code since the attached entity( that is t) has missing information, please check my answer

Comment: Hmm, if its to do with trailers missing info, then I would have to load trailers->bookings->work->requests->Items->users->Permissions .... to get the trailer to delete... what a pain, thats like the whole graph.

Comment: Nope, when I do by id, it says "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager." even after I attach it.